# Empty .NET Tab in Add Reference Dialog

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

In Visual Studio 2010 beta when I try to add a reference to a Silverlight 4 project I get an empty list on the .NET tab. I know that it is filled in asynchronously now but I've waited over 10 minutes and it never fills. It seems to work in other projects – it just seems to be Silverlight that it has trouble with. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Silverlight projects this tab would have to filter out GAC assemblies because it is not reasonable to show items unless they can be delivered to the client. On most systems that would make it an emtpy list. Note that Anthony's items are not in the GAC. I'll give you fair odds that he has some sort of project build search path that includes the folder mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The list I get is surprisingly short but not empty.  It lists everything found in my "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0" folder.  Check that such a folder exists on your system.  However these are only core dlls, the SDK dlls and toolkit dlls are missing.  To get to those I have to use the Browse tab and simply find them with the file system.  I has assumed this to be a result of being a Beta and I expect the .NET list will work better in RTM.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in VS2010 - you can submit it as such on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Answer (score 0):

rip,

I've created a sexy visual studio extension that will help you to add reference **faster**. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879/)

[image]

Regards...

Muse Extensions